# What kind of environment variables does Emacs expect to find in .profile, .bash_profile etc?

Tags: environment

When I startup `spacemacs` I get the following message:

> You appear to be setting environment variables ("PATH") in your
>   .bashrc or .zshrc: those files are only read by interactive shells, so
>   you should instead set environment variables in startup files like
>   .profile, .bash_profile or .zshenv.  Refer to your shell's man page
>   for more info.  Customize `exec-path-from-shell-arguments' to remove
>   "-i" when done, or disable`exec-path-from-shell-check-startup-files'
>   to disable this message

What are the usual variables `spacemacs\emacs` expects to find in the profile, especially the `emacs` related ones?

Comment: `emacs` doesn't use `.profile` or `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`, your shell does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a feature of the emacs package exec-path-from-shell, https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell. The message is trying to do you a favour in warning about PATH variable definitions in configuration files that are not read by non-interactive shells.

Many Emacs commands use command line programs to do the real work. The package reads your PATH setup to find out all places you have these executable files.

Just like the message says.

Comment: It's not a *standard* Emacs feature. The user has installed the non-standard `exec-path-from-shell` package, which is responsible for this behaviour.

Comment: Answer amended.

Answer (score 5):

By default, Emacs does not look at your shell config files.

The behaviour you are seeing is on account of a third-party elisp package named `exec-path-from-shell` which you have installed.  Maybe spacemacs installs this by default.

This will probably help:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `finder-commentary` <kbd>RET</kbd> `exec-path-from-shell` <kbd>RET</kbd>